# Why does it keep returning "null"?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FirstIO{
    static BufferedReader comein;

    public void ReadTextFile(){
        try {
        comein= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vocab.txt"));
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        FirstIO l= new FirstIO();
        System.out.println(comein);
    }

}
```

Why does it keep returning "null"? This is my "Object name":C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vocab.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not call the method `ReadTextFile` thus giving you error NPE.

**solution** call the `ReadTextFile` method first

```
FirstIO l= new FirstIO();
l.ReadTextFile();
System.out.println(comein);
```

**Another solution**

you can do it in the `FirstIO` constructor so you wont call the method

```
public class FirstIO{
static BufferedReader comein;

public FirstIO(){
    try {
    comein= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vocab.txt"));
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){

    FirstIO l= new FirstIO();
    System.out.println(comein);
}
```

}

Comment: +1, but maybe he meant to do that in the constructor? Just a thought :)

Comment: @Obicere I dont think so, he added a return void. but maybe he is trying to do a constructor. Ill edit.

Comment: "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vocab.txt" needs to use the escape sequence for \. It should be "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\vocab.txt". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html for more information